# Query filter does return filtered value in my SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am creating SSRS report but this filter  `starttime between @StartDateTime and @EndDateTime and UID like @uIdCondition and Type in (@Type)` mentioned in the below query does not return any filtered value. Could someone guide me what am I doing wrong?

Also, I am not sure how to combine all in one so that all my filter will work. Currently, fist `if else` works fine but the problem is in the below query.

Here is the table script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpLog](
        [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
       [LoggedTime] [datetime] NULL,        
        [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
        [Type] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
        [UID] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_EmpLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

Insert statement

```
INSERT INTO EmpLog (Id, LoggedTime, StartTime, Name,Type,UID) VALUES (1,'2021-02-20 01:15:44.647','2021-02-20 01:15:44.647', 'abc', 'cde','YY');
INSERT INTO EmpLog (Id, LoggedTime, StartTime, Name,Type,UID) VALUES (2,'2021-02-21 01:15:44.647','2021-02-21 01:15:44.647', 'mmm', 'nnn','gg');
INSERT INTO EmpLog (Id, LoggedTime, StartTime, Name,Type,UID) VALUES (3,'2021-02-22 01:15:44.647','2021-02-22 01:15:44.647', 'hhh', 'kkk','ll');
```

This script works if put it alone like this

```
declare @empNameCondition varchar(50)
if @empName = '' or @empName is null or len(@empName) = 0
Begin 
  select ID, LoggedTime, startTime,Type, Name, uID
  from [EmpLog]
  order by ID, loggedTime, UId, Name,Type
End

else

Begin 
  set @empNameCondition = '%' + @empName + '%'

  select ID, LoggedTime, startTime,Type, Name, uID
  from [EmpLog]
  where Name like @empNameCondition
  order by ID, loggedTime, UId, Name,Type

end
```

Second script also runs if I run it separatly:

```
declare @UIdcondition varchar(50)
    begin
      if @UId = '' or @UId is null or len(@UId) = 0
        set @UIdCondition = '[a-z0-9]%'
      else 
        set @UIdCondition = @UId
    
      select ID, LoggedTime, startTime,Type, Name, uID
      from [EmpLog] where 
        starttime between ''2021-02-20 01:15:44.647' and '2021-02-20 01:15:44.647'
        and UID like @uIdCondition
        and Type in (@Type)
    
    end
```

But When I combine both script together, the last section of filter does not return anything.

```
  DECLARE @empName varchar(50)
  DECLARE @UId VARCHAR(50)
  DECLARE @StartDateTime VARCHAR(50)
  DECLARE @EndDateTime VARCHAR(50)
 declare @empNameCondition varchar(50)
 set @uid='YY'
 set @type ='cde'
if @empName = '' or @empName is null or len(@empName) = 0
Begin 
  select ID, LoggedTime, startTime,Type, Name, uID
  from [EmpLog]
  order by ID, loggedTime, UId, Name,Type
End

else

Begin 
  set @empNameCondition = '%' + @empName + '%'

  select ID, LoggedTime, startTime,Type, Name, uID
  from [EmpLog]
  where Name like @empNameCondition
  order by ID, loggedTime, UId, Name,Type

end
 
declare @UIdcondition varchar(50)
  
begin
  if @UId = '' or @UId is null or len(@UId) = 0
    set @UIdcondition = '[a-z0-9]%'
  else 
    set @UIdcondition = @UId

  select ID, LoggedTime, startTime,Type, Name, uID
  from [EmpLog] where 
    starttime between ''2021-02-20 01:15:44.647' and '2021-02-20 01:15:44.647'
    and UID like @uIdCondition
    and Type in (@Type)

end
```

Comment: what you trying to achieve? your create table query doesn't have source column

Comment: Not really a minimal reproducible example, also full of syntax errors. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68449359/edit) your question to fix the errors and also include definitions (and values) for the variables: `@StartDateTime`, `@EndDateTime`, `@uIdCondition` and `@Type`.

Comment: Hi @KetanKotak, Updated my question. As I am using this query in my SSRS report. I want to combine both first and 2nd part of query so that I can use it as single query.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning, If I run the same query in my report. I will not get any syntax error. Also, as I mentioned in my question, I want to combine both in a single query. I have already supplied table structure and insert statement so I thought that will help someone to help me.

Comment: Your insert statements still have errors. Nobody here can see over your shoulder, so if you would like an explanation as to why particular values of `@StartDateTime`, `@EndDateTime` and `@Type` do not work you'll have to show us how you defined them and what values they store.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning, I have updated my question. Can you please have a look. Thanks

Comment: I don't see how you can be running this exact code in your report without errors. e.g.: Your last example defines and sets `@IdCondition` but then uses `UID like @uIdCondition`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235096/discussion-between-rjlearn-and-alwayslearning).

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning, sorry that was typo.. Just corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execute following query for your desired result

```
DECLARE @empName varchar(50)
DECLARE @UId VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @StartDateTime VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @EndDateTime VARCHAR(50)

SET @StartDateTime = '2021-02-20 01:15:44.647'

  SELECT ID, LoggedTime, startTime,Type, Name, uID
  FROM [EmpLog] 
  WHERE
  Name LIKE CASE WHEN ISNULL(@empName,'') <> '' THEN '%'+@empName+'%' ELSE Name END
  AND UID LIKE CASE WHEN ISNULL(@UId,'') <> '' THEN '%'+@UId+'%' ELSE UID END
 -- AND starttime between @StartDateTime and @EndDateTime  --this condition is not clear in question as it should be check for all or only when @starttime parameter is passed
 AND  StartTime BETWEEN CASE WHEN ISNULL(@StartDateTime,'') <> '' THEN @StartDateTime ELSE '1900-01-01' END AND CASE WHEN ISNULL(@EndDateTime,'') <> '' THEN @EndDateTime ELSE '2099-12-31' END
```

Comment: Hi @KetanKotak, It looks that you have not included all my conditions into your query. Please simply below query with all the conditions. Thanks!

Comment: what can be parameter in type? you can use the same syntax case when